# How to find function range?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I have an arbitrary function or inequality (consisting of a number of trigonometrical, logarithmical, exponential, and arithmetic terms) that takes several arguments and I want to get its range knowing the domains of all the arguments. Are there any Java libraries that can help to solve a problem? What are the best practices to do that? Am I right that for an arbitrary function the only thing can be done is a brute-force approximation? Also, I'm interested in functions that can build intersections and complements for given domains.

**Upd.** The functions are entered by the user so the complexity cannot be predicted. However, if the library will treat at least simple cases (1-2 variables, 1-2 terms) it will be OK. I suggest the functions will mostly define the intervals and contain at most 2 independent variables. For instance, definitions like

```
y >  (x+3), x ∈ [-7;8]
y <= 2x, x ∈ [-∞; ∞]
y =  x, x ∈ {1,2,3}
```

will be treated in 99% of cases and covering them will be enough for now.

Well, maybe it's faster to write a simple brute-force for treating such cases. Probably it will be satisfactory for my case but if there are better options I would like to learn them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach and depending on how crazy your function can be (see EDIT) it might give you the universal solution to your problem.

1. Compose the final expression, which might be rather complex.
2. After that use [numerical methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_optimization) to find minimum and maximum of the function - this should give you the resulting range.

**EDIT**: Only in the case that your final expression is not continuous the above would not work and you would have to divide into continuous sections for each you would have to find min and max. At the end you would have to union those.

Comment: couldn't resist the urge to say that the function will need to be differentiable - there are monsters that are continuous but nowhere differentiable, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_differentiable

Answer (score 2):

Notational remark: I assume you want to find the [range](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Range.html) of the function, i.e. the set of values that the function can take.

I think this problem is not simple. I don't think that "brute force" is a solution at all, what does "brute force" even mean when we have continuous intervals (i.e infinitely many points!).

However, there might be some special cases where this is actually possible. For example, when you take a *sin(F(x))* function, you know that its range is [-1,1], regardless of the inner function F(x) or when you take Exp(x) you know the range is (0,+inf).

You could try constructing a syntax tree with information about the ranges associated to each node. Then you could try going bottom-up through the tree to try to compute the information about the actual intervals in which the function values lie.

For example, for the function Sin(x)+Exp(x) and x in (-inf, +inf) you would get a tree

```
   +          range: [left range] union [right range]
  / \
sin  exp      range [-1, 1]  ,   range: (0,+inf)
 |    |
 x    x
```

so here the result would be [-1, 1] union (0, +inf) = [-1, +inf).

Of course there are many problems with this approach, for example the operation on ranges for +  is not always union. Say you have two functions F(x) = Sin(x) and G(x) = 1-Sin(x). Both have ranges [-1,1], but their sum collapses to {1}. You need to detect and take care of such behaviour, otherwise you will get only an upper bound on the possible range (So sort of codomain).

If you provide more examples, maybe someone can propose a better solution, I guess a lot depends on the details of the functions.

@High Performance Mark: I had a look at JAS and it seems that its main purpose is to deal with multivariate polynomial rings, but the question mentioned trigonometric, logarithmic and other [transcendental functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_function) so pure polynomial arithmetic will not be sufficient.

Comment: You're right about the notation, I'll fix that. Concerning the brute-force algorithm, I mean the approximation to a certain precision, for sure we cannot cover intervals completely. And about the algorithm - yes, there are a lot of special cases to be treated. That's why I'm looking for a ready-to-go decision where someone has done all the dirty job :) I suggest I'm not the only one interested in solution so probably they already are. My functions are entered by user and I cannot predict their complexity. However, I suggest in most cases they are very simple and complex cases can be skipped.

Comment: @Dzmitry: CAS typically can 'cover the intervals completely' (express them symbolically with algebraic expressions on sets, ready to be evaluated at given precision and usable to determine if any given number is an element or not). (note: brute-force != approximation to certain precision. brute-force == exhaustive search of the problem's solution space)

Comment: It looks to me like a problem in set arithmetic, with a significant extra twist in that some sets -- those describing intervals -- may be infinite.

Comment: @GregS, not only set arithmetic. It is a problem of symbolic algebra, for example suggestion that union is the way to go above is really misleading. Here's another example the example with F(x) = sin(x) and G(x) = 0.5 shows clearly that you have to be able to simplify the given expression F(x)+G(x) and providing the function range is continuous you could search for minimum and maximum which would give you the range (this might not be easy).

Comment: @Unreason: generally, you're right but from the practical point of view I think that ''brute-force'' is the term that describes what I wanted to say quite clear. Maybe, I'm wrong. Anyway, will have a look at CAS, probably it will help.

@GregS: in my application it would be enough to evaluate simple cases, I guess. For the complex ones with an infinite complexity and respectively impossibility to evaluate interval boundaries in a reasonable time it will be satisfactory to provide a warning about that.

Cannot believe there are no developed approaches to solve the problem to some extent.

Comment: @Unreason: You are absolutely correct. It is more complicated than I thought.

Comment: @Dzmitry, I am sure that in your mind it was clear, however neither Krystian nor me could understand your use of 'brute force', hence the note. It might be useful for you to read first paragraph of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search so that you get the concepts right. Also, see my answer, it might actually be useful.

Comment: @Unreason: thanks, will try to be more precise the next time. I'm already thinking on your suggestion in terms of my problem. Probably it's a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that this is a natural problem to tackle with a Computer Algebra System.  I googled around and [JAS](http://krum.rz.uni-mannheim.de/jas/) seems to be the most-cited Java CAS.

If I had to confine myelf to numeric approaches, then I'd probably tackle it with some variety of interval computations.  So: the codomain of sin is [-1,1], the codomain of exp is (0,+Inf), and the codomain of exp(sin(expression)) is ...

over to you, this is where I'd reach for *Mathematica* (which is callable from Java).